# Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was trying to create a neural network that actually learns chess from its played games. It can learn by playing against itself.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import chess

# Define the neural network architecture
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES), activation='softmax')
])

# Prepare inputs and outputs for training
dataset = []

inputs = np.zeros((len(dataset), len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)))
outputs = np.zeros((len(dataset), len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)))
for i, game in enumerate(dataset):
    board = chess.Board()
    for j, move in enumerate(game):
        input_ = np.zeros(len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES))
        input_[move.from_square*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)+move.to_square] = 1
        output_ = np.zeros(len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES))
        if j != len(game)-1:
            output_[game[j+1].from_square*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)+game[j+1].to_square] = 1
        inputs[i] = input_
        outputs[i] = output_

# Train the neural network on the dataset
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(inputs, outputs, epochs=10)

# Prepare the dataset of previously played chess games
dataset = []
for i in range(1000):
    board = chess.Board()
    game = []
    while not board.is_game_over():
        input_ = np.zeros(len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES))
        for move in board.legal_moves:
            input_[move.from_square*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)+move.to_square] = 1
        output_ = model.predict(np.array([input_]))[0]
        best_move_index = np.argmax(output_)
        best_move = chess.Move(best_move_index // len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES),
                               best_move_index % len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES))
        if board.parse_san(str(best_move)) in board.legal_moves:
            board.push(best_move)
        else:
            print(f"Illegal move: {best_move}")
        print(board)

# Play chess games against itself
board = chess.Board()
while not board.is_game_over():
    input_ = np.zeros(len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES))
    for move in board.legal_moves:
        input_[move.from_square*len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES)+move.to_square] = 1
    output_ = model.predict(np.array([input_]))[0]
    best_move_index = np.argmax(output_)
    best_move = chess.Move(best_move_index // len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES),
                           best_move_index % len(chess.SQUARE_NAMES))
    board.push(best_move)
    print(board)
```

When I run that code, the Error I got was unfamiliar. I never saw that error before.

### Epoch 1/10
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/structured_function.py:254: UserWarning: Even though the `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly` option is set, this option does not apply to tf.data functions. To force eager execution of tf.data functions, please use `tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode()`.
warnings.warn(

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 32>()
30
31 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
---> 32 model.fit(inputs, outputs, epochs=10)
33
34 # Prepare the dataset of previously played chess games

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
1695                 logs = tf_utils.sync_to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
1696                 if logs is None:
-> 1697                     raise ValueError(
1698                         "Unexpected result of `train_function` "
1699                         "(Empty logs). Please use "

ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

I know, that it suggest that Neural Network did not create any log files, but how do I fix it?

I tried different techniques, even asked GPT-4 about the error, It too didn't know how to solve that, answer was no where to be found on google. I tried to write the code again, and visualize what went wrong